# «Верхова їзда» — правильно чи ні?

Tags: росіянізм

Чи є назва спорту «верхова їзда» калькою з російської? Якщо так, то як тоді правильно називати цей вид спорту?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так, «**верхова їзда**» та «**їзда верхи**» — цілком нормативні словосполучення.

Наприклад, у «Словнику української мови» в 20 томах [читаємо](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=39695&page=1255):

> Парфорсна їзда: <…> у цирку — різновид *їзди верхи*, за якої наїзник виконує акробатичні вправи на коні, який долає штучні перешкоди.

Або в «Енциклопедії історії України» [бачимо](http://resource.history.org.ua/cgi-bin/eiu/history.exe?Z21ID=&I21DBN=EIU&P21DBN=EIU&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=eiu_all&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=TRN=&S21STR=Kremenetskii_Litsei):

> Виняток становили тільки т[ак] зв[ані] таланти — предмети, що входили до циклу фізичного та естетичного виховання (*верхова їзда*, танці, фехтування, музика, малювання тощо).

Стаття про це є [й у Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%97%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Також існує поняття *[кінний спорт](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82)*, що, однак, не тотожне верховій їзді. Спорт має на увазі якісь змагання, а їзда верхи з метою задоволення чи якоюсь іншою, не пов'язаною зі змаганнями метою за визначенням не є спортом.

Є й інші словосполучення, як-от «їхати конем», «кінна їзда», «кінна прогулянка».

Post Scriptum: Питання поставлено не зовсім коректно — «калька» і «правильно» не є взаємовиключними поняттями. Калькування (не лише з російської) — це лише один із способів утворення нових слів/конструкцій у мові. Навряд «верхова їзда» є калькою з російської, та й якщо калька звучить природно і вкорінилася, то це не є чимось поганим (поганим є витіснення давніших слів/сполучень кальками/варваризмами).